# To find radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^{2n}x^{n^{2}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How to find radius of convergence of the  power series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^{2n}x^{n^{2}}$? That raised to $n^2$ part confusing me.Can I do this? Instead of taking $\frac{1}{n}$th root can I take $\frac{1}{n^{2}}$ root for applying root test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your series is

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^n\;\;,\;\;a_n=\begin{cases}0,&n\text{ is not a square}\\{}\\2^{2k},&n=k^2\end{cases}$$

Thus, by the Cauchy-Hadamard Formula

$$\frac1R=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(2^{2\sqrt n}\right)^{1/n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}4^{1/\sqrt n}=1$$

and thus the radius of convergence is $\;R=1\;$ .

The answer's already been given, yet your series, as it is treated and as you wrote, is **not** a power series as formally defined. Thus, it is probably that in this exercise you should *first* try to present the series as a powers one and then find its convergence radius.

Comment: Happy Holidays my friend!  Actually, the series is a power series with all coefficients on non-squared terms equal to $0$.  Your analysis quite aptly shows that this is true.

Comment: @MarkViola Don't agree: it is **not** a power series *as given formally* and thus Cauchy-Hadamard and other tests cannot be applied to the series **as given**. One *must* take the coefficients as shown above in order to be able to apply these tests and formulas. And Happy New Year to you and everyody else!

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$\sqrt[n]{|2^{2n}x^{n^2}|}=4|x|^n$$

For $|x|<1$, $\limsup_{n\to\infty}4|x|^n=0$ and for $|x|>1$, $\limsup_{n\to\infty}4|x|^n=\infty$.

Inasmuch as the series of interest diverges if $|x|=1$, we find that the series of interest converges if and only if $|x|<1$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the root test.  You have
$$\left|2^{2n} x^{n^2}\right|^{1/n} = 4|x|^n.$$
This quantity goes to zero if $|x| < 1$ and fails the root test otherwise.
Therefore the series converges absolutely for $|x| < 1$.

Comment: It appears that we posted our solutions at nearly the same time.  It is of interest to note that we can also view the series of interest as a power series where the coefficients are zero on all of the non-squared terms.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the ratio test: $$\left\lvert\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right\rvert=\left\lvert\frac{4^{n+1}x^{(n+1)^2}}{4^nx^{n^2}}\right\rvert=4\left\lvert x\right\rvert^{2n+1}$$

This ratio converges to $0$ if $\left\lvert x\right\rvert<1$, and diverges to $\infty$ if $\left\lvert x\right\rvert>1$. So the radius of convergence is $1$.